# Passing data from HTML to component Angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular, and I'm trying to do something which sounds very simple, but which I'm finding very difficult.  I've got an *ngFor statement which creates a new div for each item in the collection and displays a value in that div using double braces {{ }}.  I want to pass that value into my component.ts but have been unable to figure out how to do so.

Here's one of the things I have tried:

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let auditType of auditTypes; let i=index">
          <br />
          <a (click)="filterByAuditType(auditType)">
              <div [selection]=auditType [id]="'AuditType' + i" class="filterChoices" (click)="highlightSelected($event)">{{auditType}}</div>
          </a>
</div>
```

The value of "auditType" is what I want to pass in to the component, so I can perform jQuery actions on it.

Component:

```
export class ComponentTeamsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   @Input() selection: string;

 ngOnInit() {
this.checkIfSelected(this.selection);
}

checkIfSelected(selection: string): void {
    $('*').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('highlightMenu')) {
            if ($(this).attr('id').indexOf('AuditType') > -1) {
                this.filterByAuditType(selection);
            }
         ---  //more code
    }
});
```

My understanding now is that @Input won't work if the component is on the same level as the HTML (i.e., not a Child component).  Please help if you know something that will work.

Comment: You have just passed `auditType` into component by `<a (click)="filterByAuditType(auditType)">`. Why not just keep it in your component somewhere?

Comment: where is `auditTypes` in your component. give some example.

Comment: @Pengyy I think you have saved me!  I can't wait to try it out!

Answer (score 3):

See below example to understand the concept for ***ngFor** in angular 4.

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let Country of countryList; let i=index" (click)="highlightSelected(Country)" name = "name">{{Country.name}}</div>
```

YourComponent.ts

```
export class ComponentTeamsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   countryList:any[];
   ngOnInit() {


      this.countryList = [
        { name: "United States"},
        {name: "Australia"},
        {name: "Canada"},
        {name: "Brazil"},
        {name: "England"}
      ];
   }


    highlightSelected(selectedCountry) {
       console.log(selectedCountry.name);
       // your rest code goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To pass the data from HTML (template) to TS (component) you can either use two-way data binding by syntax `[(ngModel)]`, or `getElementbyID` methd. You can [learn more about `ngModel` here](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel).

Example.

HTML:

```html
<input type="text" name="someInput" [(ngModel)]="someInput">
```

TypeScript:

```
someInput: String = "";
```